# Buidling and securing Angular and node rest APIs using Google authorization

Tags: node.js, angular, express, authentication, gwt

My REST API uses Node.js and Expressjs, I also have a separate Angular 6 app which makes use of the API endpoints. I want to integrate Google login into the app. I.e. from the Angular app, a user can log in via Google. The rest APIs should only be accessible to logged in users.

What are the best libraries/approaches for this?

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into OAuth 2.0, this is an authentication protocol which is used for logging in a 3rd party service. Google have their [OAuth 2.0 docs here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).

You could implement this by hand, or you could use a library such as [Passport.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport). Passport allows you to create multiple "strategies" for logging in, so you might make a Google strategy and a Facebook strategy, that would allow users to login with Google or Facebook. With Passport you tend to setup passport itself, and then pull in some additional strategy modules which implement the main Google OAuth code, you then supply a few additional functions which let you interact with your database after the various Google API requests have been made.

Passport and the passport google strategy will handle the API "dance" with Google, and they will then give you the users google profile which you can use to add the user to your database, or look them up if they're an existing user. You can then use passport and a session library to assign a session cookie. That should give you enough of an overview to get going, there are a plethora of guides online for this so you shouldn't need to go at the implementation blind.

Comment: how can i wire it with Angular? Here node doesnt have any UI.Angular should do all the logins

Comment: If this is your first time doing OAuth. I'd suggest experimenting first with server side rendering and leave out Angular. You can do this in a test express app to begin with. Once that's working, then move into Angular.

Comment: Most of the OAuth login process is server side and with redirects, so there shouldn't be much of a UI to build. Simply create a server side endpoint with passport which does the process, then get Angular to send the user to that endpoint. Passport will then redirect the user to Google's login page, that will then redirect the user back to your Angular app. Once you're in the angular app, take the tokens google gave you, make a http request to passports google callback route and pass it the tokens google gave you.

Comment: So basically, Angular will kick off the process, and then it'll proxy the data returned google to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I used the library **auth0**. The trick with auth0 is that you are using their library and servers to do the authentication (tokens and so on) and they manage everything.

In their web page you have a tutorial explaining how to use it with angular
https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/01-login

and then how to integrate it with nodejs:
https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/nodejs/01-authorization

Comment: is there a way with out using auth0? i wanted to do it without custom providers

Comment: Sincerely, I do not know.